# What does it mean the value 5 as the return of get in conflict of cplex?

Tags: python, get, conflict, cplex

I am using cplex.conflict for a problem and when i use cplex.conflict.refine and then ask for the cplex.conflict.get it gives the value 5 for some of the constraints (an infeasible example). Does anyone knows what it means? 
Here is an example in python:

```
> python
Python 2.7.6 (default, Jun 22 2015, 17:58:13) 
[GCC 4.8.2] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import cplex
>>> c = cplex.Cplex()
>>> c.variables.add(names = ["x0"])
>>> c.linear_constraints.add(lin_expr = [[[0], [-1.0]], [[0], [1.0]]], senses = "LL", rhs = [-10,9]) 
>>> c.conflict.refine(c.conflict.linear_constraints())
>>> c.conflict.get()
[5, 5]
>>>
```

The api only refers to returned values of -1, 0 or 3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`c.conflict.get()` may return `conflict.constraint_type` as well. In your case, the two constraints are members of the conflict and cplex returns types of the constraints:

```
>>> c.conflict.group_status[5]
None
>>> c.conflict.constraint_type[5]
SOS
```

i.e., your constraints are of SOS-type which is strange as SOS constraints are for integer variables (binary). If you add a redundant constraint, e.g.

```
>>> c.linear_constraints.add(lin_expr = [[[0], [-1.0]], [[0], [1.0]], \
[[0], [1.0]]], senses = "LLL", rhs = [-10,9,10]) 
>>> c.conflict.refine(c.conflict.linear_constraints()) 
[5, 5, -1]
```

meaning the last one is excluded as not being a member of the conflict. I would recommend you to use `c.conflict.get_groups()` for more information.

**Edit:**

If you specify variables' types when defining everything works fine:

```
>>> c.variables.add(names = ["x0"], obj=[1.0], types=[c.variables.type.continuous])
...etc...
>>> c.conflict.refine(c.conflict.linear_constraints()) 
Refine conflict on 3 members...

Iteration  Max Members  Min Members
     1            2            0
     2            2            1
     3            2            2

[3, 3, -1]
```

Comment: Thank you, this is very helpful. Is there a way to know when the output of c.conflict.get() is a conflict.constraint_type?

Comment: I don't think cplex is supposed to return `constraint_type` when calling `c.conflict.get()`, It might be a bug in this case or just unpredicted behavior.